# Can I host Cypress to a server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

So we're using Cypress + Cucumber to perform E2E UI tests. Everything is running fine, whenever I trigger the script, it shows the cypress pop-up, and I trigger a few tasks manually. Now we want our QA person to use the same prompt to test a few specific scenarios as they will. I know one way to trigger the test is during the CI/CD pipeline, but I was wondering if there's a way to host the app on some server, and a QA person can trigger a particular flow whenever they want.

So far I found `cypress run --browser chrome --headed --no-exit --port 9000` command to keep the server active and run the tests when you click on it. But when I copy the URL and open it in another browser, I see an error saying that it can't run the test because the browser was not opened by cypress.

Please let me know if there's a way to achieve it.

Comment: Which browsers are u targeting other than chrome ?

Comment: @pixlboy I am targeting chrome for now

Comment: Ok I was thinking maybe you wat other browsers as your question read `But when I copy the URL and open it in another browser`. I guess when you copy paste the generated url then cypress looses the context of the tab, basically the process id of running window needs to be known for Cypress to take control of DOM elements.

Comment: The idea is to host the app in such a way that a QA person can open the Cypress page and trigger a specific test whenever they want. That's why I was trying to copy and paste the cy generated URL in to a different window.

Comment: Understood now, one workaround that I know is to install standalone version or global npm module of cypress in QA machine and then in you can trigger a cypress run command pointing to your dev/qa/prd server.

You will need this also `npm install --save-dev start-server-and-test`